# Calculating sum - after rows are grouped using groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to groupby a particular column in a dataframe and calculate sum of subgroups thus created, while retaining( displaying) all the records in each subgroup.

I am trying to create my own credit card expense tracking program. (I know there are several already available, but the idea is to learn Python.)

I have the usual fields of 'Merchant', 'Date', 'Type' and 'Amount'

I would like to do one of the following:

1. Group items by merchant, then within each such group, split the amount under (two new columns) 'debit' and 'credit'. I also want to be able to sum the the amounts under these columns. Repeat this for every merchant group.
2. If it is not possible to split based on 'Type' of the transaction (that is, as 'debit' and 'credit'), then I want to be able to sum the debits and credit SEPARATELY and also retain the line items (while displaying, that is.)Doing a sum() on the 'Amount' column gives just one number for each merchant and I verified that it is an incorrect amount.

My data frame looks like this:

```
   Posted_Date  Amount    Type       Merchant  
0   04/20/2019  -89.70   Debit            UNI  
1   04/20/2019   -6.29   Debit          BOOKM  
2   04/20/2019  -36.42   Debit       BROOKLYN  
3   04/18/2019  -20.95   Debit  MTA*METROCARD  
4   04/15/2019  -29.90   Debit           ZARA  
5   04/15/2019   -7.70   Debit         STILES
```

The code I have, after reading into a data frame and marking a transaction as credit or debit is:

```
merch_new = df_new.groupby(['Merchant','Type'])
merch_new.groups

for key, values in merch_new.groups.items():
    df_new['Amount'].sum()
    print(df_new.loc[values], "\n\n")
```

I was able to split it the way below:

```
    Posted_Date  Amount   Type   Merchant  
217  05/23/2019  -41.70  Debit        AT  
305  04/27/2019  -12.40  Debit        AT  



 Posted_Date  Amount    Type Merchant  
127   07/08/2019    69.25   Credit       AT  
162   06/21/2019   139.19   Credit       AT
```

Ideally, I would like something like the below:
[the line items are displayed and a total for a given subgroup. In this case for merchant 'AT' and ideally sorted by date.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHHHu.png)

```
    Date    Merchant    Credit  Debit  
305 4/27/2019   AT  0   -12.4  
217 5/23/2019   AT  0   -41.7  
162 6/21/2019   AT  139.19  0  
127 7/8/2019    AT  69.25   0  

                  208.44    -54.1
```

It appears simple, but I am unable to format it in this way.

EDIT:
I get an error for rename_axis():
   `rename_axis() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'`
and if I delete the index argument, I get the same error for 'columns'

I searched a lot for the usage (like Benoit showed) but I cannot find any. They all used strings or lists. I tried using:
`rename_axis(None,None)` 
and I get the error:
`ValueError: No axis named None for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

I don't know if this is because of the python version I am using (3.6.6). I tried on both Spyder and Jupyter. But I get the same error.

I used:
`rename_axis(None, axis=1)` and I seem to get the desired results (sort of) 
But I am unable to understand how this is being interpreted since there is no qualifier specified as to which argument it is reading into for "None". Can anyone please explain?

Any help is appreciated! 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: What is your desired output exactly for the sample data you've included in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you try to achieve something like this:

```py
In [1]:
## Create example
import pandas as pd
cols = ['Posted_Date', 'Amount', 'Type', 'Merchant']  
data = [['04/20/2019', -89.70, 'Debit', 'UNI'],
        ['04/20/2019', -6.29, 'Credit', 'BOOKM'],
        ['04/20/2019', -36.42, 'Debit', 'BROOKLYN'],
        ['04/20/2019', -6.29, 'Credit', 'BOOKM'],
        ['04/20/2019', -54.52, 'Credit', 'BROOKLYN'],
        ['04/18/2019',  -20.95, 'Credit', 'BROOKLYN']]  
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, data=data)

## Pivot Table with aggregation function ='sum'

df_final = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Amount', index=['Posted_Date', 'Merchant'],
               columns=['Type'], aggfunc='sum').fillna(0).reset_index().rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)

df_final['Total'] = df_final['Debit'] + df_final['Credit']

Out [1]:

    Posted_Date Merchant    Credit  Debit   Total
0   04/18/2019  BROOKLYN    -20.95  0.00    -20.95
1   04/20/2019  BOOKM       -12.58  0.00    -12.58
2   04/20/2019  BROOKLYN    -54.52  -36.42  -90.94
3   04/20/2019  UNI         0.00    -89.70  -89.70

​
```

Comment: Thank you, Benoit. I could work with your solution too. I just edited the question to clarify. Is there a way to get the results that way?

Comment: Also, to Benoit's solution, if I want to add another column titled 'Total' which would be the sum of Debit and Credit columns, how can I do that?

Comment: I just edited my answer, was it something like this that you were looking for ?

Comment: Thank you, Benoit; I see you cleaned up the way it is being displayed and added Posted Date to the result. I tried the same but I get a KeyError for 'Posted_Date'. I tried adding it to the df_final (that you created before using pivot table functionality):     `df_final = df_new[['Posted Date','Merchant', 'Type', 'Amount']].groupby(by=['Merchant', 'Type']).sum().reset_index() `      But I still get the same error...  any suggestions?

Comment: Well this error means that you have no column named `posted_Date` in your dataframe. Isn't called just `Date` ?  Just edit this code with the real columns of your dataframe

Comment: that is what i thought. But I do have the column and made sure the column name was correct. another quick question: would it be possible to add an additional column titled "total" that gives the sum of debit and credit? Should I assign the result of the pivot output in a dataframe view and then create a column and perform addition?   Apologies if it is a silly question. I have just started working with pandas.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard, I have edited the answer with what I think you want to have

Comment: Thanks a lot, Benoit!  I am able to display the Posted Date now. And, the last line of code definitely is simple. : ) However, I get `TypeError: rename_axis() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'` When I remove the rename_axis(), the columns names are off and I cannot add the debit and credit columns.